# $(w^2+x^2).(y^2+z^2)$ is always divisible by which of the max no. Where w;x;y;z are positive odd integers?

Tags: number-theory

> Q 
>   $(w^2+x^2).(y^2+z^2)$ is always divisible by which of the max no where w,x,y,z are positive odd integers?

Options given: 20;8;4;2

My Approach:

I Choose ($9^2$+$5^2$).($7^2$+$3^2$) to get a maximum number.I should be divisible by 2,4 and 8 both.

Is my approach right towards the problem?  Correct me if i am wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$(2a+1)^2\equiv1\pmod8\implies(2a+1)^2+(2b+1)^2\equiv2$$

So,the highest power of $2$ in $(w^2+x^2)\cdot(y^2+z^2) $ will be $2$

Now we are free to choose exactly one of $x,w$ to be divisible by $5,$ so that $5\nmid(x^2+w^2)$

Comment: How u get $(2a+1)^2+$(2b+1)^2$ ?

Comment: @Jack, "positive odd integers" and $$(2a+1)^2=8\dfrac{a(a+1)}2+1\equiv1\pmod8$$

Comment: You mean i put w=$(2.a+1)^2$ and x=$(2.a+1)^2$.I added up both I got $8$.$a$.(a+$1$)+$2$.

Comment: @Jack, Put $w=2a+1, x=2b+1$

Comment: I got $4$.($a^2$+$b^2$)+$4$.(a+b) +$1$.I cannot conclude any thing

Comment: @Jack, Focus more, you should get $$4(a^2+b^2+a+b)+2$$ which is divisible by $2$ not by $4$